# Run real "Bios Setup" in virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware

Normally if we want to change Bios Setting, we need to restart the PC and when system boot up we press the hot key (F2 or F10) to go "Bios Setup", then change the setting.

However, I would want to do real Bios Setup from Window Environment...Is it possible to copy the image of Bios (of my computer) to a binary file? then setup a virtual machine to run it and do all the changes? If it is impossible with existing tool (VirtualBox, Qemu, VMWARE)...is it possible to write a special virtualization software to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to see an answer too here... Why couldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 10):

Go to your settings of the virtual machine go to system > motherboard click EFI on

Boot your machine and type in the shell (you need to wait a bit)

"exit" then you will go into the BIOS EFI if you want to quit hard power it off and to turn off the bios for boot again reverse the settings...

(For virtualbox)